# FullCalendar: - where to edit sizing?

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

this is probably a palm-to-forehead question, but I can't spend more time digging around. I'm using FullCalendar in combination with EventsManager.  I need to resize the calendar to full-width of the website; retaining responsiveness of the calendar.

I have tried to replace aspectRatio in js files to "2" from default 1.35 - nothing changes on displayed calendar. I have reviewed the AspectRatio file and am not sure where you're suggesting the codes for 'Getter' or 'Setter' are supposed to be implemented within the js files.

Clarity about Where the edits are to take place to improve the appearance of the calendar would be extremely helpful! Thank you,
Site for review is: https://cisvaaa.org/cal/

Comment: have I missed something - it is full width of the container - which is set to grid_8 - which is ? 2/3 ? of the page

Comment: Yeah its in a `.container_12 .grid_8 {
    width: 620px;
}` class, also why have you wrapped it in a pre tag?

Comment: _"...am not sure where you're suggesting the codes for 'Getter' or 'Setter' are supposed to be..."_  ...they are function calls, so you can call them in your code whenever you need to manually update the setting. See https://fullcalendar.io/docs/dynamic-options for more details

Comment: Anyway I think the others are right. The reason the calendar doesn't fill the width of the page is nothing to do with fullCalendar. As https://fullcalendar.io/docs/aspectRatio says: _A calendar is a block-level element that fills its entire available width_. So if the calendar is not filling the width of the page it's because you have placed it inside another element which has a restricted width. In this case (at least when I loaded the URL just now) you've put it inside a `<div class="grid_10` which appears to have a fixed width of 780px. That's what you need to change if you want to alter it